# easyAccordion jquery plugin callbacks

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, horizontal-accordion

Does easyAccordion jquery plugin have any callback function to do something after the accordion item is opened?

I want to fade in the title of image after it is opened completely.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any provisions for a callback in the source, but it looks simple enough that adding one wouldn't be very hard.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just modify the plugin js file:

```
jQuery(this).find('dt').not('active').click(function(){     
    jQuery(this).activateSlide();
    //begin add
    if (settings.afterSlide) { 
        settings.afterSlide();
    }
    //end add
    clearTimeout(timerInstance.value);
});
```

then add afterSlide parameter when you define the accordion.

```
$('#your-accordion-container').easyAccordion({ 
   afterSlide: function() { blah }
});
```